# concatenate row data of a column based on group

Tags: sql, t-sql, merge, concatenation

Thank you for anyone who is help. I am seeking help to create an sql script to do the following.

Have the following table

| REF 1 | REF 2 | Ref 3 | wt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 91112 | 43111 | 14928-001 | 2 |
| 91112 | 43111 | 14928-002 | 5 |
| 91113 | 42555 | 14940-001 | 3 |
| 91112 | 43111 | 14928-003 | 4 |
| 91114 | 42556 | 14941-001 | 1 |

where the yield would be great like the following

| REF 1 | REF 2 | REF 3 | WT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 91112 | 43111 | 14928-001/002/003 | 11 |
| 91113 | 42555 | 14940-001 | 3 |
| 91114 | 42556 | 14941-001 | 1 |

I stumped at how to get 14928-001|002|003 as a merged value
this is for T-SQL
Thank you,

Comment: Try to look into the `CONCAT` tsql function >> https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: MS SQL version 12.0.2269.0

Comment: Concat is easy for columns, but to do for rows, i have not got a clue.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to accomplish. It appears that you want to group rows together by `REF 1` and `REF 2` values, but how does `Ref 3` fit in? Does the part of the value preceding the dash (`'14928'`) have to match? If it doesn't match is that a separate result row, a different concatenated value, discarded, ... ? Do the remaining parts (`'001'`, `'002'`, ...) need to be in a specific order?

Comment: Thank you @HABO for the question. REF3 is the column i want to concat the row with the  same data for ref1 and ref3.

Comment: So if there are three rows for `REF 1` `90000` and `REF 2` `00000` with `Ref 3` values of `10000-006`, `12000-042` and `11000-000` you want one result row with `REF 3` containing `12000-042/000/006` since the order doesn't matter and any part before the dash is a good place to start. `REF 2` has no significance as an input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using SQL Server 2017 or later, you could use the `STRING_AGG` function. But since you are using SQL Server 2014, you have to use the `FOR XML` trick.

I have a solution, and it isn't elegant and there is most likely a better way to this, but here goes.

First, I set up a table variable and put your data in it. I then used a common table expression and some grouping to create an intermediate result:

```sql
Declare @Data TABLE(REF1 INT NOT NULL, REF2 INT NOT NULL, REF3 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, WT INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @Data(REF1, REF2, REF3, WT) 
VALUES (91112, 43111, '14928-001', 2), 
(91112, 43111, '14928-002', 5), 
(91113, 42555, '14940-001', 3), 
(91112, 43111, '14928-003', 4), 
(91114, 42556, '14941-001', 1);


;WITH Step1 AS 
(
SELECT REF1, REF2, REF3, 
        LEFT(REF3, CHARINDEX('-', REF3) - 1) AS REF3_LEFT, 
        SUBSTRING(REF3, CHARINDEX('-', REF3) + 1, LEN(REF3) - CHARINDEX('-', REF3)) AS REF3_RIGHT,
        WT
FROM @Data 
) 
SELECT p.REF1, p.REF2, p.REF3_LEFT,
    (SELECT '/' + REF3_RIGHT FROM Step1 AS sub 
        WHERE p.REF1 = sub.REF1 AND p.REF2 = sub.REF2 
        ORDER BY sub.REF3_RIGHT 
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS suffixes, 
        SUM(WT) AS WT
FROM Step1 AS p
GROUP BY REF1, REF2, REF3_LEFT 
ORDER BY REF1, REF2;
```

The result of this look like the following:

| REF1 | REF2 | REF3_LEFT | suffixes | WT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 91112 | 43111 | 14928 | /001/002/003 | 11 |
| 91113 | 42555 | 14940 | /001 | 3 |
| 91114 | 42556 | 14941 | /001 | 1 |

This is very close... all we need to do now is replace the leading / of suffixes with a - and the concatenate it to REF3_LEFT and we will have it. So I will make another common table expression from the first and get the result you have shown above:

```sql
Declare @Data TABLE(REF1 INT NOT NULL, REF2 INT NOT NULL, REF3 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, WT INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @Data(REF1, REF2, REF3, WT) 
VALUES (91112, 43111, '14928-001', 2), 
(91112, 43111, '14928-002', 5), 
(91113, 42555, '14940-001', 3), 
(91112, 43111, '14928-003', 4), 
(91114, 42556, '14941-001', 1);


;WITH Step1 AS 
(
SELECT REF1, REF2, REF3, 
        LEFT(REF3, CHARINDEX('-', REF3) - 1) AS REF3_LEFT, 
        SUBSTRING(REF3, CHARINDEX('-', REF3) + 1, LEN(REF3) - CHARINDEX('-', REF3)) AS REF3_RIGHT,
        WT
FROM @Data 
), Step2 AS 
(
SELECT p.REF1, p.REF2, p.REF3_LEFT,
    (SELECT '/' + REF3_RIGHT FROM Step1 AS sub 
        WHERE p.REF1 = sub.REF1 AND p.REF2 = sub.REF2 
        ORDER BY sub.REF3_RIGHT 
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS suffixes, 
        SUM(WT) AS WT
FROM Step1 AS p
GROUP BY REF1, REF2, REF3_LEFT 
) 
SELECT REF1, REF2, CONCAT(REF3_LEFT , '-', SUBSTRING(suffixes, 2, LEN(suffixes) -1)) AS REF3, WT 
FROM Step2;
```

And this is the result:

| REF1 | REF2 | REF3 | WT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 91112 | 43111 | 14928-001/002/003 | 11 |
| 91113 | 42555 | 14940-001 | 3 |
| 91114 | 42556 | 14941-001 | 1 |

There is the desired output you have shown. Obviously you do not need the table variable since you have the table and data, but it should be easy for you to replace `@Data` with the actual table name.

Comment: Thank you Very much @Bjorg P , i have seen similar solution for my scenario using xml path as a way to concat the data.  but your example is much easier to follow. i wish  i can upvote your solution but the site does not allow me.